# Should tags' wiki include 'Related questions'?

Tags: discussion, tags

By clicking on the tags links, the user moves to a list of questions which are tagged by that specific tag and a list of related questions appears to him relatively. As an example, see the wiki of the [reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation) tag.

```
Do we need a list of related questions in the wiki of the tags?
```

I think this list of related questions is not only *unnecessary*, as the users have access to a *complete* list of related questions of the tag; but also it is *harmful* and *misleading* to the users and should be removed as the list may not include good questions which present the concept and use of the tag.

EDIT: A list of good examples of on- and off-topic questions on each tag does not have any harm, on the other hand, it really helps the users to know the tags and their usage better; but I think the list of exemplar questions on the tags can be harmful as we have them on the site right now. They are not well organized and reviewed. The list of the exemplar questions on the wiki of the tags may be harmful because:

As stated in [this answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1271/15723), `Some will be "bad" examples - usage that is wrong, or not necessarily wrong but not perfect either.`; the user expects the sample questions be really on-topic and wants to learn from these sample questions about the sites policy on each tag; so, by reading wrong examples, they will be mislead and consequently;

- From the usage perspective;

  1. user will tag the newer questions wrongly;
  2. user will do edits on questions and re-tag questions with the wrong concept;
  3. by reading wrong examples and having wrong concept about the correct usage of the tags, and wrong usage of the tags, the user may face down-votes and major edits on his question and this is absolutely discouraging to some (not all) of the users.
- From the maintenance perspective;

  1. we should put extra time and effort to list the best and most on-topic questions in the wikis of the tags; if we don't pay enough attention to these lists, then we will not have good/working tags wikis at all;
  2. choosing off-topic and on-topic questions for each tags needs some time and discussions between users, as we have not finished our edits on the tags of the questions yet, thinking and working on finding best lists for tag wikis will be waste of time;
  3. reviewing the existing lists of exemplars in wikis needs another attention, who guaranties that the existing exemplars are well-chosen?

Comment: Can you clarify how a list of exemplar questions might be harmful and misleading to users? (Assuming it's a list of *good* questions with the tag, and not a list of *bad* questions that shouldn't actually have that tag.)

Comment: @ff524 I edited my question relatively, but I think I did not well answered your concern.

Comment: You seem to be responding to the possibility that the list of "Related questions" includes bad questions. If that's the case, it should be edited to only include good questions - that's not a reason to eliminate this list entirely. Have you seen any such lists that include bad questions?

Comment: If this is a serious problem - that there are, in fact, tag wikis that include bad or irrelevant questions on their list of "Related Questions" - then you should be able to identify some tag wikis that have this problem and link to them here. As far as I have seen, our tag wikis are actually reasonably good in this respect.

Comment: @ff524 In the reputation tag, we have four questions listed as exemplars, and I really don't think that the last two questions are good questions to be listed in the tag's wiki. Those questions will not help the users significantly become familiar with the usage of the tag. They may be on-topic for the tag, but they are not that much on-topic and not at the level to be put on the wiki. I think, questions which are outstandingly on-topic for the tag should be well-chosen and put on the tag wikis.

Comment: If you think those specific questions are bad examples of "reputation" questions then you can suggest an edit to remove them from the list (mentioning in the "edit summary" why you think so). I happen to think those questions *are* good examples of the 'reputation' tag.

Comment: @ff524 You are at a higher level of English knowledge and if you think they are good, they are good; I will not edit the wiki. But, I really think that the exemplar lists should be well chosen. We need to put some more time and effort to choose the best examples for such lists. I think that the existing lists are just in the wikis, because the editor of the wiki wanted to put something in the wiki and not to leave it empty, they are not well-chosen or at least they *can* be reviewed in the future.

Comment: If your argument is that people should choose "Related Questions" thoughtfully, fine, I agree. If your argument is that people shouldn't put any "Related Questions" in tag wikis because someone *might* put one that isn't the best example possible, I disagree. If your argument is that many of the current "Related Questions" in tag wikis are very bad, I also disagree.

Comment: @ff524 My arguments are: *people should choose "Related Questions" thoughtfully* and *some* of the current "Related Questions" in tag wikis are very bad and should be edited in the future.

Comment: As currently written, your question asks "Do we need a list of related questions in the wiki of the tags?" - which is a completely different question from "People should choose 'Related Questions' thoughtfully, because some of the current 'Related Questions' in tag wikis are very bad and should be edited in the future"

Comment: @ff524 your question about harms of bad lists brought us to this point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The purpose of a list of exemplar questions in a tag wiki is as follows:

As we know, not all questions are tagged perfectly. Sometimes, people use a tag that is incorrect, or not really necessary.

When a user clicks on a tag, they see the list of all questions with that tag. However, not all of these are necessarily "good" examples of usage of the tag. Some questions on the list of *all questions with the tag* will be "bad" examples - usage that is wrong, or not necessarily wrong but not perfect either.

In your own words, the reason for listing some exemplar questions in the tag wiki is exactly what you said: to show

> good questions which present the concept and use of the tag.

That is, to show how the tag is intended to be used (which is not necessarily how it was always used in practice.) That's why it's not a comprehensive list of every question with a tag - it's a selected list of a few that exemplify what the tag is about.

All of the possible negative effects you mention are general side effects of any community-prepared resource, including the entire tag wiki (not just the list of questions).  We deal with this the way we do with any community-prepared resource: users can suggest edits to improve anything that seems wrong to them, and the community reviews the edits and approves the ones that they agree with.

There is never any "guarantee" of quality with anything on this site; that's why we have lots of eyes to review things and fix anything that needs fixing.

So in summary,

- If your argument is that people should choose "Related Questions" thoughtfully, fine, I agree completely. People should make *all* suggested edits carefully.
- If your argument is that people shouldn't put any "Related Questions" in tag wikis because someone might put one that isn't the best example possible, I disagree.
- If your argument is that many of the current "Related Questions" in tag wikis are very bad, I also disagree. The ones I've come across seem fine to me.

Comment: I am looking for the answer to the following question: *Is it a good idea to have such lists of questions in the wikis?* and I think you don't see any problem having such kind of wikis on the site.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I gave reasons why it *is* a good idea to have lists of such questions in the wiki, as long as they are chosen well. I also gave reasons why the possibility of someone *not* choosing well is not a good reason not to have these lists at all.

Comment: I got my answer. Thanks. :)